# How to Integrate angular 2 with php and mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, angular

How can we integrate Angular 2 using MySQL database and php for database connectivity ?? As angular 2 and XAMPP using the different ports.

so please help me to give approach to work with back end and angular 2(front end).I am new in angular 2.

Comment: Firstly, your question is quite broad and moreover you should first try yourself and ask if you're stuck with some aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has the `Http` class to perform AJAX calls to your backend. On the PHP side you need to handle those (typically REST) calls and implement your business logic. You can either use a full blown PHP framework such as `Symfony` or `Laravel` or a mini framework (basically a request router) such as `Lumen` or `Slim`.